# Regex to include and exclude without lookahead

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to match a URL containing both "foo" and "bar" but not "bar=0".

I'm trying to do this in Google Analytics and it doesn't support lookahead expressions.

So I am matching urls containing both "foo" and "bar" with this expression `(foo.+bar)` but how do I negate urls with "bar=0"?

Comment: Could you please post some of those URLs ?

Comment: Any luck with the regex?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
\bfoo\b.+\bbar\b(?:$|=[^0]|[^=])
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/marUIfFzAz

Comment: This won't match URLs with `bar=3` which seems to be accepted by the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.+bar[^\=]
```

for this to make any sense, please post a example of a url you are trying to validate